# Affine Permutations as a Coxeter Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, coxeter-groups

I was stuck trying to show that the group of $n$-affine permutations (i.e. bijections of $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} f(i)-i =0$ and $f(i+n)=f(i)+n$ for a certain $n \in \mathbb{N}$) is a Coxeter group.

More concretely, I wanted to show that it is generated by the “elementary transpositions” that swap $[i]$ and $[i+1]$ as congruence classes modulo $n$ (leaving the rest fixed). I tried by hand to construct a general formula for an arbitrary such permutation, but the notation soon gets very cumbersome and I cannot conclude.

Online/on books I just found this fact stated as “clearly true (by looking at the action on the right of these transpositions on any permutation)”, which I do not really get.

Comment: The point in that every $n$-affine permutation $p$ corresponds to some finite permutation $\sigma$. By multiplying $p$ by the permutation $p_i$ corresponding to a transposition $(i,i+1)$ you can make $\sigma$ closer to $1$ (because $\sigma$ is a product of such transpositions).